# How to retrieve or enable Radio Button based on database value?

Tags: c#, winforms

When I use textbox they successfully working **like this:**

```
padd.txtCustomerName.Text = this.dtvContacts.CurrentRow.Cells[20].Value.ToString();
```

[image]

but how to apply in Radio Button.

```
padd.rbtLOI.Text = this.dtvContacts.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: What is the value in `this.dtvContacts.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
if (this.dtvContacts.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString() == "LOI")
{
   padd.rbtLOI.Checked = true;
}
else
{
   padd.rbtConfirmPO.Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: `this.dtvContacts.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString()` what is the value of this.